# How to use analyzer in Hibernate Search?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, infinispan

When I use Infinispan with Hibernate, I need to use Analyzer to find results which includes the key word.

But when I search the keyword `SNO_NO_D6-11100` with query like:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = CSECore.searchManager
                  .buildQueryBuilderForClass(Hierarchy.class).get();
Query query = queryBuilder
        .keyword().onField("path").matching("SNO_NO_D6-11100").createQuery();
```

It seperates`SNO_NO_D6-11100` to `SNO_NO_D6` and `11100` then find them respectively and merge 2 results together. There will be some results incorrect.

If I ignore the analyzer, it will just find the exact match which is also incorrect. Is there a solution that Analyzer can ignore the "-" ??

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for results which contain the term `SNO_NO_D6-11100` in the `path` field?

Comment: Yes, I need Analyzer to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a phrase query (see section 5.1.2.4 [in the hibernate query dsl](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#search-query-querydsl)) instead:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.phrase().onField("path").sentence("SNO_NO_D6-11100").createQuery();
```

The two terms will still be separated, but since it is a phrase query it will search for the two separate terms occurring consecutively.  So it will not be able to distinguish between "SNO_NO_D6-11100" and "SNO_NO_D6 11100", but I'm guessing that is probably acceptable.

Comment: Thx for the reponse, that does really helpful. But I just wondering if there is method to write my `Analyzer` like I wrote my own `Custom Bridge`?

Comment: You can set the analyzer to whatever you like, in a few different ways, see: [section 1.6: Analyzer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e392)

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate 5.10.3, we can override analyzers at search time:

```
FullTextEntityManager fte = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
QueryBuilder qb = fte.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Article.class)
                .overridesForField("path", "keywordanalyzer")
                .get();
```

Where `ngram_search` is a custom analyzer defined as follow:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "keywordanalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class))
```

Note that `KeywordTokenizerFactory` does not split the input, it basically emits the entire input as a single token.